# GetItem by date in DynamoDB results in ValidationException

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need a data filtered by date but I am getting an error

> **Error ValidationException:** The provided key element does not match the schema

My table has a primary key (only partition key) of `id`.

```
async function fetchDatafromDatabase() {  // get method fetch data from dynamodb
    var date = todayDate();
    var params = {
        TableName: table,
        Key: {
            "date": date
        }
    };

    let queryExecute = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        dynamoDB.get(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
                rej(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success! get method fetch data from dynamodb");
                res(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
    });
    const result = await queryExecute;
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: `date` needs to be a string as DynamoDB has no concept of a date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting an item from DynamoDB, we must pass primary key, in this case, its just partition key 'id' (assuming it is numeric and storing epoc date)

```
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var date = Date.now();
console.log("date", date);
var params = {
  TableName: "test2",
  Key: {
    id: date,
  },
};
documentClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
```

Complete Example to put an item and get it.

```
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var date = Date.now();
documentClient.put(
  {
    TableName: "test2",
    Key: {
      id: date,
    },
  },
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log("err", err);
    if (data) {
      documentClient.get(
        {
          TableName: "test2",
          Key: {
            id: date,
          },
        },
        function (errGet, dataGet) {
          if (errGet) {
            console.log("Error", errGet);
          } else {
            console.log("Success", dataGet);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```